# Python library for hierarchical sets (or set operations on trees)

Tags: python, data-structures, set, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

Let's imagine I have the following hierarchy/tree:

```
                Commit
             /     |    \
           /      Fix     \
         /       /   \      \
  Feature   CodeFix  DocFix  Refactoring
```

I want to be able to define sets where the elements are the leaves of this tree. The way to do it with standard python sets would be to list all the leaves to be included, e.g. `{Feature, CodeFix, DocFix}`. What I want is to use a shortcut and pass the entire sub-trees instead. For that, we need some abstraction level that handles that, let's say class `HSet`. With such class, it should be possible not only to create a set like this:`HSet(Feature, BugFix, DocFix)` but also like this: `HSet(Feature, Fix)`. Both alternatives should yield the same object and represent the same set since `Fix == CodeFix|DocFix` according to the hierarchy.

Having such a shortcut would be especially beneficial if `Fix` had dozens of children. Having to create large sets in the code manually is exactly my use case. Except for set creation, I need also a shortcut for listing the elements in a set. For example, if a set contains all the leaves in the hierarchy, it could be represented by the root of the hierarchy, which would be `{Commit}` for the example provided above. Please see the examples that will hopefully illustrate the concept better.

```
>>> from somelibrary import HSet 

>>> commit = HSet.create_root_element("Commit")
>>> feature, fix, refactoring = commit.add_children("Feature", "Fix", "Refactoring")
>>> code_fix, doc_fix = fix.add_children("CodeFix", "DocFix")

>>> str(code_fix | doc_fix)
'{Fix}'
>>> str(code_fix | refactoring)
'{CodeFix|Refactoring}'
>>> str(feature | fix | refactoring)
'{Commit}'

>>> str(~ code_fix)
'{Feature|DocFix|Refactoring}'
>>> str(~ commit)
'{}'
>>> str(~ (feature | refactoring))
'{Fix}'
```

**I am curious if there exists such `somelibrary` that implements this.**

#### Update: Implementation

In the meantime, I wrote my implementation of the concept I was talking about. But I am always concerned about not reinventing the wheel. So, **I would be grateful to pointers to existing data structures in the standard python library or custom libraries that can be used to fully/partially replace my code.**

#### hset.py

```
from typing import List

from hset.tree import _Tree


class HSet:
    def __init__(self, subtrees: List[_Tree], domain: _Tree):
        self.subtrees = domain.collapse_subtrees(subtrees)
        self.domain = domain

    @classmethod
    def create_root_element(cls, label: str) -> 'HSet':
        tree = _Tree(label, None, [])
        return cls([tree], tree)

    def add_children(self, *labels: str) -> List['HSet']:
        if len(self.subtrees) != 1:
            raise ValueError(f"Cannot add children to this HSet since it has multiple root elements: {self}")
        if self.subtrees[0].children:
            raise ValueError(f"This HSet already has children.")

        trees = self.subtrees[0].add_children(*labels)
        return list(map(lambda t: self._create([t]), trees))

    def _create(self, subtrees: List[_Tree]) -> 'HSet':
        return HSet(subtrees, self.domain)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{' + "|".join(map(lambda x: x.label, self.subtrees)) + '}'

    def __invert__(self) -> 'HSet':
        return self._create(self.domain.complement(self.subtrees))

    def __or__(self, other: 'HSet') -> 'HSet':
        if self.domain != other.domain:
            raise ValueError("Cannot perform operations on HSets with different domains")

        return self._create(self.domain.collapse_subtrees(self.subtrees + other.subtrees))
```

#### tree.py

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, List


@dataclass
class _Tree:
    label: str
    parent: Optional['_Tree']
    children: List['_Tree']

    def add_children(self, *labels: str) -> List['_Tree']:
        children = [_Tree(label, self, []) for label in labels]
        self.children = children
        return children

    def collapse_subtrees(self, subtrees: List['_Tree']) -> List['_Tree']:
        if self in subtrees:
            return [self]
        elif not self.children:
            return []
        fully_covered = True
        res = []
        for child in self.children:
            collapsed_child = child.collapse_subtrees(subtrees)
            fully_covered &= (collapsed_child == [child])
            res.extend(collapsed_child)

        return [self] if fully_covered else res

    def complement(self, subtrees: List['_Tree']) -> List['_Tree']:
        if self in subtrees:
            return []
        elif not self.children:
            return [self]
        return [elem for lst in map(lambda x: x.complement(subtrees), self.children) for elem in lst]
```

Cheers, Hlib.

Comment: It doesn't look like the tree actually matters in any way. You could just use regular sets.

Comment: Can you show an example of something you would do with these "hierarchical" sets, that you either can't do with normal sets at all, or that would give a different answer with normal sets?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I updated the question, hope it's more clear now

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused.

Comment: It's not clear at all. Can you show a concrete example of something you would use these trees for? Trees are useful for some things. Sets (in the python sense) are useful for some other things. It's really not clear what you want.

Comment: It's really not clear what behaviour you are looking for – the requirements seem contradictory. The initial description says that ``{a, b, c}``, ``{a, bc}``, and ``{abc}`` (I assume ``{a, bc}`` means ``{a, {b, c}}``?) should be the *same* object ``{a,b,c}``. One could do that with unpacking/flattening. However, the new content says the HierarchicalSet should preserve its subtrees, meaning ``{a, bc}`` could *not* be the same as ``{a, b, c}``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added the concrete example, the one with a,b, ab is really confusing, I agree

Comment: @Stef, the concrete example of the tree could be a hierarchy of classes, please see the update

Comment: I'm afraid the newest batch isn't that helpful either. Classes and especially subclasses are not set-like, so ``HierarchicalSet({BaseException})`` exploding to all the (current? dynamic? abstract?) subclasses is not helpful – it implies a huge machinery that seems out of scope. It also (assuming set-ness of classes) conveniently leaves out some edge cases, e.g. what would ``HierarchicalSet({BaseException}).difference({KeyBoardInterrupt})`` actually be? It cannot be set-like, because that set would both *contain* ``BaseException`` and *exclude* some of its subsets.

Comment: Please be aware that the first part is not just confusing, it is contradictory with the later ones. As long as the question contains both, it is immediately unsolvable.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry again for the confusion. My ability to express myself with natural language is apparently quite poor. So as the last attempt I decided to explain it with the code. Update 3 contains the implementation of the class that I needed. This shouldn't be ambiguous anymore.  Please take a look if you are still interested. Cheers, Hlib.

Comment: For future reference, you might want to read up on [what Set means in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Even though I don't think I miss any knowledge of what sets and their semantics in python are, your link encouraged me to thoroughly check the docs. I found out that the `Flag` class exactly implements the behavior I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what I was looking for was the [Flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag) class.

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class CommitType(Flag):
    FEATURE = auto()
    CODE_FIX = auto()
    DOC_FIX = auto()
    REFACTORING = auto()
    FIX = BUG_FIX | DOC_FIX
    COMMIT = FEATURE | FIX | REFACTORING

>>> CommitType.DOC_FIX | CommitType.CODE_FIX
<CommitType.FIX: 6>
>>> CommitType.DOC_FIX | CommitType.REFACTORING
<CommitType.REFACTORING|CODE_FIX: 10>
>>> CommitType.FEATURE | CommitType.FIX | CommitType.REFACTORING
<CommitType.COMMIT: 15>

>>> ~CommitType.CODE_FIX
<CommitType.REFACTORING|DOC_FIX|FEATURE: 13>
>>> ~CommitType.COMMIT
<CommitType.0: 0>
>>> ~ (CommitType.FEATURE | CommitType.REFACTORING)
<CommitType.FIX: 6>
```